# Exception Handling in WCF's Completed Event

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, exception

I am wondering how to catch Exception in my `WCF's` completed event method and show it to the User in the `MessageBox`.

I call the `GetProductTypeAsync();` method that fetches records from the Database. I want to catch any Exception that occurs here and send it to the `service_GetProductTypeCompleted` Event where it should show the `Exception Message` to the User.

```
public List<ProductType> GetProductType()
{
    List<ProductType> productType = new List<ProductType>();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Get_ProductType", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ProductType pType = new ProductType(Convert.ToInt32(reader["pkProductTypeID"]), reader["Name"].ToString());
                    productType.Add(pType);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Catch Exception and send to the service_GetProductTypeCompleted Event Method
    }
    return productType;
}
```

Here is the `service_GetProductTypeCompleted` Event

```
void service_GetProductTypeCompleted(object sender, GetProductTypeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Count != 0)
    {
        productTypes = e.Result.ToList();
        cboProductType.DataContext = productTypes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send an `exception` from your *service*, the client would receive generic error message:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."

If you want to catch the *specific exception* on the client side, then you should throw what is called `FaultException` from the *service*. These are *Soap Faults* and can be recognized by any *consumers*. Please note that your consumers for your service is not always .NET consumer, so throwing CLR exception wouldn't be recognized. That's the reason why you need to `throw` `Soap exception`.

E.g. this is how you would catch and throw `Fault Exception`

```
catch (FaultException<AnyTypeThatCanBeSerialized> ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/799258/WCF-Exception-FaultException-FaultContract) for more details on `wcf Faults`

Answer (score 0):

The FaultException does not flow to Silverlight. You will need to return a class similar to the following from your service layer:

```
public class ServiceReturnInformation<T>
{
    public T DataContext { get; set; }

    private IList<string> _warnings;
    public IList<string> Warnings
    {
        get { return _warnings ?? (_warnings = new List<string>()); }
        set { _warnings = value; }
    }

    private IList<string> _errors;
    public IList<string> Errors
    {
        get { return _errors ?? (_errors = new List<string>()); }
        set { _errors = value; }
    }
}
```

If an exception occurs, your service needs to catch the exception and set the Errors/Warnings properties.

```
    var result = new ServiceReturnInformation<Employee>();
    try
    {
        // Do something
        result.DataContext = GetEmployee();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.DataContext = null;
        result.Errors.Add(ex.Message);
    }

    return result;
```